# Where test data will be stored in stripe account?

Tags: stripe-payments, dashboard, test-data

I have used stripe as the payment in my system. I have tried test keys to process the payment and it is returning successful after submission w.r.t test api keys, but where as I look in the stripe dashboard I can't find any test data which was processed.

If you click on account settings there is a pop-up in that if you click on data tab it shows option to delete all test data, but I can't find where to view all the processed test data.

Is there an option to view all test data which were submitted ? If so where it's available.

where to find all submitted test data in stripe dashboard?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In the left menu bar of the Stripe dashboard, there is a [toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Wyc.png) you can use to switch between the Live and Test views.

[image]

Note that the toggle only changes the *view* -- you can always use both test mode and live mode, no matter what the toggle is set to. This is done by specifying which set of [API keys](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys) you're using to make a charge.

Comment: Where should I View the test data which was submitted in the site ?? In dashboard , the API Keys  section above it said no api version set yet. Also in the webhooks I have defined my site url. What else should be done to view the test data?

Comment: If the API keys screen there is no API version yet, that means you haven't made any request using your keys then. When you make your first request, the version will be set to the current version (which is currently 2015-09-23).
Because you haven't made any requests yet, there is no data to see, neither in test nor in live mode.

Comment: The design's changed, so I can't see any switch in this place right now.